# ５桁以内の半角数字でかつ「0だけ」は許可しない正規表現

Tags: java, 正規表現

そのような正規表現は書くことができるのでしょうか。
宜しくお願い致します。
0→out
00→out
000→out
0000→out
00000→out

1→ok
123→ok
0123→ok
00123→ok
12345→ok

Comment: 一口に正規表現と言ってもコマンドやプログラミング言語によって実装が異なってくるので、想定している利用場所を明記してもらった方がよいかと。質問は後からでも [編集] できます。

Comment: どうしても正規表現でなければいけませんか？　例えば入力を文字列として受け取り、整数変換（例えばRubyならto_i）を使って0になったらout、ならなければokで判定できると思うのですが。

Comment: XY問題では無いでしょうか。まず「5桁以内の半角数字」を抽出し、「0だけ」のものは除外すると言う方法では対処できない問題ですか？

Answer (score 8):

否定先読みアサーション`(?!...)`を使って、先に「0だけ」を除外するのはどうでしょうか。否定先読みは、ほとんどの処理系で使えると思います。

```
^(?!0+$)\d{1,5}$
```

Pythonで、次のようにテストしたらすべてあいました。

```
import re

pattern = r'^(?!0+$)\d{1,5}$'
print(re.search(pattern, '0'))
```

Javaの場合も正規表現は同じです。先読みは、最近のプログラミング言語であれば同じように使えるはずです。

```
String str = "0";
String pattern = "^(?!0+$)\\d{1,5}$";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
System.out.println(m.find());
```