# 正規表現で二つの文字の繰り返しをマッチングさせたい

Tags: 正規表現

正規表現で二つの文字の繰り返しをマッチングさせたい
これは文章の境界線として使われているパターンです。

たとえば、

```
こたこたこたこたこたこたこたこたこたこたこた

なぬなぬなぬなぬなぬなぬなぬなぬなぬなぬなぬなぬなぬなぬなぬ
```

このような区切りとして使っている場合に無意味にひらがなや記号が交互に並びます。

同じひらがなが

```
なななななななななななななななななななななな
```

このようであれば簡単ですが、文字は決まっていないので厄介です。

これら二つの文字が交互に繰り返されているときにマッチングさせる正規表現はどのように書きますでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 「二つの文字」ですが、それらは同じ文字ではなく異なる文字なのでしょうか？

Comment: ありがとうございます。異なる文字という意味になります。こたこたこたこたみたいな感じです。

Comment: [ひとつ前のご質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/74429/19110)でも指摘がありましたが、どの正規表現エンジンを使いたいのかを質問文で明示していただきたいです。特定の正規表現エンジンでは使えない拡張機能があるからです。ちなみに、今回のものは拡張されていない正規表現では絶対にマッチできません。より正確に言うと、`Σ` を文字の集合として `L = {ww | w ∈ Σ}` は正規な言語ではありません（ポンピング補題で証明できます）。このため後方参照など何かしら拡張された正規表現を使うことになります。

Comment: ありがとうございます。御厚意､感謝しております。Boost.Regexです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

書き方は正規表現エンジンによりますが、キャプチャしたグループの[後方参照](https://qiita.com/ikmiyabi/items/12d1127056cdf4f0eea5#%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A3%E3%83%97%E3%83%81%E3%83%A3)で実現できます。

- `(..)\1+` ひらがなや記号など任意の2文字の繰り返し(改行やスペースも含む)
- `(\w{2})\1+` ひらがなやアルファベット、数字2文字の繰り返し

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。出来ました。御厚意､感謝しております。

Answer (score 3):

> 異なる文字という意味になります。こたこたこたこたみたいな感じです。

Negative lookahead(否定先読み) `(?! ... )` を使います。この場合、同じ文字の繰り返しにはマッチしません。

```
$ echo 'こたこたこたこたこた' | grep -Po '((.)(?!\2).)\1+'
こたこたこたこたこた
$ echo 'なぬなぬなぬなぬなぬ' | grep -Po '((.)(?!\2).)\1+'
なぬなぬなぬなぬなぬ

# No match
$ echo 'なななななななななな' | grep -Po '((.)(?!\2).)\1+'
```

質問内容に既視感があったので調べてみると、

[５桁以内の半角数字でかつ「0だけ」は許可しない正規表現](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/49704/)

がありました。参考になるかもしれません。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。